# I want to access a stored variable from one class from another class in python

Tags: python, python-class

I am simulating a person running with an enemy chasing the person. I am struggling in finding the code for the movement of the enemy.

```
class Person ():
    def __init__(self, limits, name)
        self.row = 0
        self.col = 0
    
    def run(self, limits):
        #movement code etc.
```

I want to be able to take the self.row coordinate from the Person, and be able to use that variable in class Enemy, to determine the movement of Enemy. Throughout the simulation I'll be changing the self.row and self.col of Person so I want the Enemy to be able to follow.

```
class Enemy ():
    def __init__(self, limits, name)
        self.row = 0
        self.col = 0

    def run(self, limits):
        if self.row > #the Person's self.row
            self.row -= 1
```

How can I use the variables from class Person and use them in class Enemy to determine the movement?

Edit:
If I make an object under class Person, how do I access that object, specifically each self.row or self.col from class Enemy?

Comment: To access to  Person attribute, you can create a Person object `person = Person(20, 30)` and then get the row by using `person.row`

Comment: There are no "variables from class Person" - everything you're storing in that class is in the form of *instance attributes*, which are specific to each individual instance of the class.  The `Enemy` would need to be given a specific `Person` instance whose location would direct its movement.

Comment: Don't have `Person` and `Enemy` do this kind of computation.  They don't need to know about each other.  You need a function (or a "Battlefield" class) to do this which uses both types of objects and understands how they interact.

Comment: @TimRoberts would I make the Battlefield class the parent class or another completely independent one?

Comment: A `Person` is not a kind of `Battlefield`, or vice versa.  `Battlefield` would CONTAIN `Person` and `Enemy` objects.

Comment: @TimRoberts what code would I use to first make person/enemy objects and then how would I put them into a Battlefield class?

Comment: How were you planning to create your `Person` and `Enemy` objects?  I suspect you need to go through some Python tutorials.